# Joomla3 создание сайта гайд

Tags: joomla

Всем привет.
Встал вопрос о создании сайта по системе гайд. :
Как я понял смысол сайта таков:
Вы читаете 20% текста на сайте, а остальные 80% закрыты и если вы хотите дочитать будьте добры оплатит.
У меня вопрос есть ли уже готовы компоненты или модули для Joomla3 для данных тем?.
Если есть то укажите пожалуйста может вы знаете компоненты или плагины о связке оплата+контент
Поделитесь своими мыслями.
Я подозреваю, что на Joomla3 есть уже готовое решение.
Спасибо